# How to insert the names of external files as a variable in a loop in XSLT?

Tags: shell, loops, xslt

I have shell script that navigates in every subdirectory (2 levels deeper) in a loop then calls transform.xsl which makes changes in the ie1.xml. There is one ie1.xml in every subdirectory called "content".

```
IFS=$'/\n\n' dirs3=( $(ls -d */) )
for i in "${dirs3[@]}"
 do
   echo $i
   cd $i
   cd content
xsltproc -o ie1.xml ../../transform.xsl ie1.xml  
   cd ../../
 done
```

That's my xsl script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dc:record">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *" />
        <xsl:element name="dc:relation">filename</xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to insert the filename of the file which is located 2 levels deeper into the following element in xsl `<xsl:element name="dc:relation">filename</xsl:element>`. Filenames should be inserted in the loop.

Comment: Isn't the name always `ie1.xml`? Or which name are you looking for? In any case, with an XSLT 1.0 processor called externally, it seems best declaring a global `<xsl:param name="filename"/>` and then use it with `<dc:relation><xsl:value-of select="$filename"/></dc:relation>` where you want to output it. On the command line you can then set the parameter as needed, e.g. `--stingparam filename ie1.xml`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen no it's not ie1.xml. The file name of the .pdf file which is located (names are always different) should be inserted in dc:relation tag of every ie.xml. The question was how to read this pdf filename then navigate 2 levels higher and save it in ie1.xml with a help of my xsl.

Comment: I mean how can use a variable as a filename in xsltproc line: xsltproc -o ie1.xml --stringparam filename %variable%  ../../transform.xsl ie1.xml

Comment: Hopefully someone knowing your shell language can help with that, I am afraid my knowledge about that is limited, I saw the question because of the [tag:xslt] and helped with that.